# onUpdate in SequenceEntityModifier

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have been looking over this doc:

http://andengine-doc.googlecode.com/hg/org/anddev/andengine/entity/modifier/SequenceEntityModifier.html

And it indicates that there is an onUpdate, but I'm seeing this error when I try to use it:

> The method onUpdate(float) from the type new
>   SequenceEntityModifier(){} is never used locally

I'm new to Java, here is my code:

```
    SequenceEntityModifier modifier = new SequenceEntityModifier(myMovemod) {

        @Override
        protected void onModifierFinished(IEntity pItem) {
            // animation finished
            super.onModifierFinished(pItem);
        }

        protected float onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

            return pSecondsElapsed;

        }

    };
```

When I add "@Override" to it, I get an error, and eclipse's only solution is to remove @override, What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to change your compiler compliance. Set it to 1.6.

Comment: Hi, A--C, I've tried to set my Compiler Compliance level to 1.6, and Clicked OK when it asked to rebuild, but I am still seeing the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the javadoc in your original question, I think the method should look like:

```
public float onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed, IEntity pItem)
{
    return pSecondsElapsed;
}
```

Otherwise you are not overriding an existing method - you are creating a new method.

Also `onModifierFinished` should be public.